# Trying To Pull Date Out Of MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, format

But I cannot Format it?  Date is saved currently in the database under a 'text' type structure  and saved a '1/1/2000'.  I'm trying to pull this info out of the database and DATE_FORMAT it to '01/01/2000' (2 digit day & month) but it's showing all dates as 12/31/1969?  Here's the query i'm using:

```
        $query = "SELECT Event_Title, Event_Details, Event_Time, Event_ID, DATE_FORMAT(Start_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM tevents ORDER by Start_Date DESC";
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

database:

```
Rows    Start_Date Ascending
1   04/30/2014
1   05/03/2014
1   05/1/2014
1   05/3/2014
3   5/1/2014
1   5/15/2014
1   5/2/2014
2   5/20/2014
1   5/23/2014
1   5/24/2014
5   5/3/2014
3   5/6/2014
1   6/21/2014
1   6/23/2014
1   6/24/2014
1   6/25/2014
1   6/26/2014
1   6/27/2014
1   6/28/2014
1   6/5/2014
1   6/6/2014
```

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your data...

Comment: `Date_Format` needs a valid date. Why are you storing them as text??

Comment: Since you're storing strings, you've got to convert these strings first to `DATE`type, then you can format the date. Better store them as date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date stored as `varchar` or `TEXT` makes life miserable so better to store as `date` or `datetime` data type.

In your case you need to use `str_to_date()` for conversion before doing any format

```
$query = "SELECT 
Event_Title, 
Event_Details, 
Event_Time,
Event_ID, 
date_format(str_to_date(Start_Date,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y') as Start_Date
FROM tevents 
ORDER by date_format(str_to_date(Start_Date,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') DESC";
```

If its just for ordering then no need to do the

```
date_format(str_to_date(Start_Date,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y') as Start_Date
```

You can directly select since its converting to the same format, for ordering its needed.

Comment: This won't fix the sort order, because it'll again sort by strings in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: I learned here that %m and %d don't need leading zeros. I hadn't thought about that before. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like its working, thanks Abhik.  I'm working with an already made database with over 18,000 records so unless there is a way to transfer TEXT to DATE without losing data I'm working with my constraints :(

Comment: well make a temp table and write a small script to transfer the data to the temp table from this table and then rename the old table and then rename the temp table to the actual table name. Thats a quick solution to transfer data without loosing data. You can even transfer data by using INSERT -- select together by doing conversion at the time of select.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a question into a closed envelope and give it to the neighbour, why can't he answer you?

'Text' means 'do not bother about the contents' for MySQL, it normally does not care about the content. If you use a `DATE` datatype, things get much easier at reading (and sorting works, and ranges, and where-clauses...) and a bit difficult on writing - you should format the dates into the form '2014-05-01' in the program code.